# The output of this code should be 0 why am I getting 1 as a result? Please tell the error

Tags: java, class, methods

Actually I am writing a method for counting total number of division by 3. My code is:

```
class Simple{  

    public static int countDivisible(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i=lowerBound; i< upperBound; i++)
        {
            if((i%3)==0)
            counter++;

        }

        return counter;

    }


    public static void main(String args[]){  

        int num;
        num = countDivisible(17,19);
        System.out.println("total= "+num);

    }        

}
```

As an example, if countDivisible(3, 9) is invoked, a value of 2 will be returned. This is because there are only two numbers, 3 and 6, that are divisible by 3 but not by 9 in the integer range [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: So, what's the error? In your code `18` is divisible. And hence output is `1`.

Comment: what is the error? the ouput 1 is right

Comment: "but not by 9". there 's nothing about that in your code.

Comment: In the range of 17 and 19, 18 is a divisible of `3` and the count is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting 18 in the condition

```
18%3 == 0
```